# Numpy ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (152,1) (151,1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have two numpy arrays both of the same shape (152, 1), i'm putting them into a mean squared error function I made which looks like this:

`return np.sum(y - y_hat, axis=1, keepdims=True)**2/len(y_hat)`

But for some reason i'm getting the error:

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (152,1) (151,1)`

I know that the error is originating with the y - y_hat because I tried to print that out to see what was happening and I got the same error. I don't know what the problem could be as this is a perfectly legal matrix operation and both the numpy array shapes are the same. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I've just realised that y_hat is short a value, I thought they were the same. sorry.

Comment: Are you *sure* `y` and `y_hat` have the same shape? The error implies `y_hat` is short a value

Comment: yea i just spotted that thanks, i feel really stupid haha.

Comment: Not answering your point, but you can use `np.mean` instead of dividing by the length.

Comment: @Learningisamess thanks i'll try that out, i'm still a bit new to numpy and i've only learnt the things i need to so I don't know too much

Comment: @Aguy Cheers, one step at the time, no worries.